# why this method is giving a null pointer exception

Tags: java

this code is supposed to read from a file and parse each entry as a double in the  point array it successfully reads from the file but whenever it tries to parse the input tp double it give null pointer exception .

```
 try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new    FileReader("dataset.csv"));
        int j = 0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String [] pointtemp = line.split(split);
            //check
            point = new double[point.length];
            for (int i = 0; i< pointtemp.length; i++){
                point[i] = Double.parseDouble(pointtemp[i]);
                System.out.println(point[i]);
            }
            points [j] = new point(point);
            j++;


    }
```

Comment: What is in your dataset.csv file? and what `split` contains?

Comment: my data set file contains random numerical data 10 columns and 1000 rows and the split is just a comma :D

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do with this line `point = new double[point.length];`?

Answer (score 4):

Your `double[]` initialization is not correct. Declare it as

```
   point = new double[pointtemp.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

try to surround it with try & catch mechanism and print (in catch) the value of pointtemp[i]. Maybe you are trying to parse an empty cell ?